# Transferring coordinates unit from Imperial to metric in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a raster with NAD_1983_StatePlane_Indiana_East_FIPS_1301_Feet coordinate.

Is there any way to transfer the coordinate to metric in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods. Two are temporary and the other will create a copy of the raster using metric coordinates.

Temporary 1

```
1. Add the raster to ArcMap.
2. Open data frame properties and select the General tab.
3. Change the display units to meters.
```

Temporary 2

```
1. Add the raster to ArcMap.
2. Open data frame properties and select the Coordinate Systems tab.
3. Pick a metric-based coordinate system.
4. OK the dialogs (you may also have to change the display units; see above).
```

Permanent 1

```
1. Open the Project Raster Tool.
2. Fill out the tool, using a metric coordinate system as the target.
```